# How to calculate?

Tags: objective-c

I just tried to calculate something. All my input is int.

```
int aveScore = (startScore/((([p1.arrayThrow count]-1)) + winPane.throws));
```

The result is (for startscore = 501 and the rest = 3 [501/3 = 167]) 100. Even tried `float aveScore` which results in something like 10359. Also didn't work:

```
int aveScore = (float) ...
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int aveScore = (int)((float)startScore / (([p1.arrayThrow count] - 1) + winPane.throws));`

EDIT:

If you want a floating point average score then it would just be:

`float aveScore = (float)startScore / (([p1.arrayThrow count] - 1) + winPane.throws);`

Comment: The result is the same: 100. But nevertheless, I've forgotten to tell, that I want the result as a float.  Should be like `float aveScore = (float) ...` but working :/